# Mysql_num_rows not Valid - PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I use the method or function mysql_num_rows() in my php code, it worked great and had no issues. I later just changed my web host. I created a new database that is identical to my old one. I changed all the information to access the database and am getting access to the new database but it is throwing an error once the code reaches mysql_num_rows. Why am I getting an error for mysql_num_rows? The results are suppose to be 0 when the function is ran because I have no information in my new database, but I also added information just so I didn't get a 0 and it is still giving my an error. Why?!!!!

Comment: Maybe it's a sign - to use [PDO](http://au1.php.net/pdo).

Comment: Maybe if you posted the error we could help.

Comment: Idk what that is or how to use it at all

Comment: At the very least, you can echo `mysql_error()` and see what the actual error message is. But if you've moved web hosts, have you also made sure that you've updated the database user's connection details to use the new database?

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like you've moved to a server with a newer version of PHP - mysql functions are deprecated, use mysqli (and convert the rest of your database functions to mysqli):
https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php